# Чи є український відповідник до слова "мазохіст"?

Tags: іменники, запозичені-слова

Значення слова знаходжу у [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=154738&page=1548):

> **МАЗОХІ́СТ**, а, ч. Особа, схильна до мазохізму.

Однак, аби все ж уникати такого масового запозичення, хотіла б і до цього слова знати український відповідник. Чи є такий / -і?

Comment: Про всяк зазначу, тямка походить від прізвишча пана [Леопольд фон Захер-Мазох](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Леопольд_фон_Захер-Мазох), до речи, нароџеного ві Львові.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Відповідник буде знайти досить важко, так як це назва психічного захворювання, що походиться від назви [людини](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B4_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%85), яка вперше дослідила це явище (як було вже зазначено у коментарях). На кшталт цього слова у нашій мові також існують такі слова як [садизм](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC) (садист), [кретинізм](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BC) (кретин) тощо. Такі слова вкрай важко замінити, бо були вони винайдені вже давно і в нашу мову потрапили також давно, того й немає у нас відповідників, які мали б точно таке саме значення.

Однак, опираючись на визначення терміну "[мазохізм](http://getword.ru/ukr/slovari.php?word=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BC&table=ukr_melnuk)"

> "Статеве збочення, при якому для досягнення оргазму необхідно
>   відчувати фізичний біль або моральне приниження з боку партнера"

можу припустити, що цей термін у певному контексті можна замінити словом "[збоченець](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C)" або ж "сексуальний збоченець", однак врахуйте, що слово "збоченець" все одно має ширше значення аніж "мазохіст".

Comment: Трішки виправлю: мазохізм — це _риса_, а не _захворювання_; якщо ця риса викликає в людини психосоціальні складнощі, їй діагностують сексуальномазохістичний _розлад_ (302.83 у DSM-5, F65.51 у ICD-10), але якщо ця риса не викликає страждань в людини, то це не підпадає під діагноз.